# What is the difference between escapeXml and escapeHtml?

Tags: html, xml, jsp, escaping

I would like to escape characters in JSP pages. Which is more suitable, `escapeXml` or `escapeHtml`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They're designed for different purposes, HTML has lots of entities that XML doesn't.  XML only has 5 escapes:

```
&lt; represents "<"
&gt; represents ">"
&amp; represents "&"
&apos; represents '
&quot; represents "
```

While HTML has loads - think of `&nbsp;` `&copy;` etc.  These HTML codes aren't valid in XML unless you include a definition in the header.  The numeric codes (like `&#169;` for the copyright symbol) are valid in both.

Comment: Ah look you added the JSP tag - I was wondering which language you were coming from.

Answer (score 19):

There's no such thing as `escapeHtml` in JSP. You normally use [`<c:out escapeXml="true">`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) (it by the way already defaults to `true`, so you can omit it) or [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) to escape HTML in JSP.

E.g.

```
<c:out value="Welcome, ${user.name}" />
<input name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
```

It will escape them as XML entities which works perfectly fine in plain HTML as well. They are only literally called XML entities because HTML entities are invalid in XML.

#### See also:

- [Java 5 HTML escaping To Prevent XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333586/java-5-html-escaping-to-prevent-xss)
- [Escaping html in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148799/escaping-html-in-java)

Comment: By "to escape HTML in JSP" you mean "to escape HTML in EL", right?

Comment: @DavidBalažic: "to escape HTML in JSP using EL". HTML doesn't harm in EL.

Comment: My point was that the function is an EL function and can not be used outside of EL. Note that I am talking about `fn:escapeXml` only (my first comment was badly worded as I misread your sentence). So: `c:out` is for JSP, while `fn:escapeXml` is for EL (which can also at end wind up in HTML, of course). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DavidBalažic: c:out is to escape HTML in JSP using JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending HTML back to the consumer I would go with `escapeHtml`.

`escapeXml` only supports escaping the five basic XML entities (gt, lt, quot, amp, apos) whereas `escapeHtml` supports escaping all known [HTML 4.0 entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html).

Comment: the solution above yours very clearly states "There's no such thing as escapeHtml" in JSP. Not sure who is correct here but I definitely need to escape XML and HTML characters which means I really need an escape HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to commons StringEscapeUtils, [escapeXml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) only deals with `<>"'&` while [escapeHtml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) covers a richer set of characters.

Comment: Why would you need to cover them? Escaping the mentioned 5 characters is enough.