# How do I print HTML tags using regex in JSP?

Tags: java, html, regex, jsp

I wanna print string, which include "`< >`" in it, to the web page using JSP. I need to replace any "`>`" and "`<`" to "`&lt`" and "`&gt`". My string should be "`java/io/Object`" or "`<init>`", etc.
Can anyone give me a pattern?

I know two method to replace strings. But I dont know how to use it.

```
    1
    String ss = s.replaceAll("(?i)<a.*?>(.*?)</a>", "$1");
    System.out.println(ss);

    2
    Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("(?i)<a.*?>(.*?)</a>");
    Matcher matcher2 = replace.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(matcher2.replaceAll(""));
```

which one will replace string fast? 
thx for ur time.
EDIT:
I am not trying to escaping html tags. The strings like "`<init>`" is not print in the web page, but it exists in the html source file, since the browser make it as a tag.

Comment: There is zero reason to use a regex in this situation.

Comment: Note that you might want to escape the other entities in HTML as well. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html might be useful.

Comment: If you want it to be fast, avoid using a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex to replace angle brackets in Java.

Your best bet is to use vanilla String methods:

```
public String replaceAngleBrackets(String s) {
    return s.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;");
}
```

This one line method executes faster and is easier to read, maintain, and re-use.

Comment: I would expect this to be **WAY** faster than anything that involves a regex... It should be extremely easy to benchmark it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is escape the HTML; and regular expressions are not the answer.

See [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java) for more information.

Comment: I am not trying to escaping html tags. The strings like "`<init>`" are not print in the web page, but it exists in the html source file, since the browser make it as a tag. @hoipolloi

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSLT tag `out`, it escapes the value to be safe to render. Put in your JSP this tag where you want your value to be rendered:

```
<c:out value="${myVar}" escapeXml="true" />
```

where `myVar` is the string variable you want to print

Comment: For the example above, this should be fine. XML != HTML though; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735900/what-is-the-difference-between-escapexml-and-escapehtml for what I mean.

Comment: I won't recommend this at least that you can be sure `${myVar}` is a valid HTML code that's not prone to XSS attack.