# How do i set scriptlet to scriptlet javascript variable

Tags: javascript, java

```
<% String email =(String) request.getSession().getAttribute("email"); 
   session.setAttribute("email", email);
%>

<script>
function test() {
var email = ${fn:escapeXml(email)}
}
</script>
```

Above does not work
I have also tried put quotes `"${fn:escapeXml(email)}";  or '${fn:escapeXml(email)}'; or "${fn:escapeXml(email)};"`
.... and none of them are working. I have also tried

If I do `<span id="email" value="${fn:escapeXml(email)}">${fn:escapeXml(email)}</span>`

It says cannot find function fn:escapeXml

Error message I got was: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`
How do I set scriptlet to variable in javascript?

Comment: Have you tried doing an online search for `fn:escapeXml`?

Comment: yes, but most of the use case is in html directly. I have not seen it could be set within javascript. there is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735900/what-is-the-difference-between-escapexml-and-escapehtml but it is not working for me. I have libtag imported....so i m not sure what is wrong.