# Spring or App-Server escape html isn't working JAVA MVC

Tags: java, html, model-view-controller, spring, escaping

i've got this in my web.xml

```
 <context-param>
   <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

and this in a jsp

```
 <spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape="true" />
```

Still I can put `<font color="red">this is red</font>`in a form and see red text on the website.

I am using EL and Taglibs to access my variables in the jsps. E.g. `<h3>${someThing.title}</h3>`

Why is this not working, what shall I do? Wrapping every EL-expression in some wrapper bloats the code and is very error prone...

Comment: So why didn't this work in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<c:out value="${someThing.title}" escapeXml="true"/>
```

Comment: that's what I don't want. No webdesigner can work with jsps full of that stuff... And if I forget putting that somewhere im prone to XSS. I want to set it once.

Comment: So maybe you could add a filter which would escape all request and session scoped parameters prior forwarding the call into jsp

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to use `<c:out>` to escape your code in the JSP. I can see how you might think that's bloated, but you can use a tag file to reduce duplication. Alternatively, use the EL's `fn:escapeXml` function.

Comment: Are these other things (content-param ...) useless? If it's really so hard to do every second site must be prone to XSS. Maybe I should look into that for a new income source :-)

Comment: Yeah it's a pain. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147958/how-do-i-prevent-people-from-doing-xss-in-java. I think `defaultHtmlEscape` only applies to the output of Spring MVC JSP tags, not raw EL expressions.