# Spring, protect against XSS or injection

Tags: java, spring, xss

The place I work has a Sencha 4.1.3 frontend, with Java + Spring 3.x backend.

Sencha sends a RESTful call to get the data. The server returns some JSON. Pretty basic stuff.

I would like to escape/remove any `<script></script>` tags from the response. Is there any annotation or anything I can use to quickly do this?

Comment: Swing? Do you mean Spring?

Comment: Why would you want/need to remove script tags from JSON?

Comment: @Alex My bad... it was late on a friday :)

Comment: Try the OWASP Java encoder project: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project#tab=Main

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent people from doing XSS in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147958/how-do-i-prevent-people-from-doing-xss-in-java)