# Usage of defaultHtmlEscape web.xml in JSTL

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl

So I have set the following parameters in my `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Will this automatically escape outputs for the field by only declaring in the JSP:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="label" name="label" value="${field.label}">`

or do I need to use the `<spring:`? Or use the `<form:` tags?

Update:
This question is just a matter of yes/no. And maybe a brief answer regarding how to activate the params in the JSP-side. My question is after I set the params in `web.xml`. So do i need to use `<spring:` or `<form:` tags in the JSP or I can use plain `<input type...` tags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent people from doing XSS in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147958/how-do-i-prevent-people-from-doing-xss-in-java)

Comment: @RomanC Not really. My question is after I set the params in `web.xml`. So do i need to use `<spring:` or `<form:` tags in the JSP or I can use plain `<input type...` tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The escaping applies only to the Spring MVC tags. For example:

```
<form:input path="field" htmlEscape="true" />
```