# spring form input fields type attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am converting some plain HTML to using spring form tags.Although it looks like
spring form input does not have the attribute type. I was able to successfully 
pass a hidden variable as follows:

```
 <form:input type="hidden" name="displayId" id="displayIdentifier"  path="displayIdentifier" value="${value1}"/>
```

Earlier the plain HTML was as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="displayId" id="displayIdentifier"  value="${value1}"/>
```

I looked online and saw that the for:input does not have the type attribute, yet it seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input tag is declared with

```
<dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>
```

That allows passing dynamic attributes, not explicitely declared in the tag. The tag simply stores their name and value and writes them as is on the generated HTML input. That allows adding a type, or a data attribute, or any attribute you want to the tag.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My understanding is that using spring form input tags, would provide output encoding by default. So by using this for the hidden field,does it provide output encoding for that hidden field?

Comment: What do you mean by "output encoding"? Do you mean html escaping, as transforming < to &lt; for example? What happens when you test it?

Comment: yes- i meant html escaping,so that say someone cant intercept and add a script tag to the hidden field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147958/how-do-i-prevent-people-from-doing-xss-in-java. But htmlEscape is true by default for input tags. Once again, why don't you test it?