# Prevent xss attack in Spring+Hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, xss, code-injection

I have spring + hibernate application.

I have a lot of fields values of which I store in database. At this fields user can type anything.

These values can be rendered on client side. Thus this script can be executed.

Is there way to handle this problem in **single** place or I should handle each situation separately ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2148120/4204904
Basically you have to set in your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```