# How to protect against XSS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, xss

I have REST server, where I receive data from client. I need to implement full XSS protection. I currently have this code, which takes take only of URL (so basically get request), but I need to make it work for all requests (POST, PUT, GET...) and data are stored in JSON. So i need a way how to check all data in json BEFORE its saved to RequestBody. I also need to implement protection against encoded possible xss attacks (it does not  even work for GET now)
Are there better ways to implement this protection or libraries which could help me? And how to do that for POST, PUT, when data are stored in json?

```
public class XSSRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    public XSSRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String parameter) {
        String[] values = super.getParameterValues(parameter);

        if (values == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int count = values.length;
        String[] encodedValues = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            encodedValues[i] = stripXSS(values[i]);
        }

        return encodedValues;
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String parameter) {
        String value = super.getParameter(parameter);

        return stripXSS(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String value = super.getHeader(name);
        return stripXSS(value);
    }

    private String stripXSS(String value) {
        if (value != null) {


            // Avoid null characters
            value = value.replaceAll("", "");

            // Avoid anything between script tags
            Pattern scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script>(.*?)</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            // Avoid anything in a src='...' type of expression
            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            // Remove any lonesome </script> tag
            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            // Remove any lonesome <script ...> tag
            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            // Avoid eval(...) expressions
            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("eval\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            // Avoid expression(...) expressions
            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("expression\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            // Avoid javascript:... expressions
            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("javascript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            // Avoid vbscript:... expressions
            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("vbscript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            // Avoid onload= expressions
            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onload(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
        }
        return value;
    }
}

@Component
public class XssFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new XSSRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Input validation is good and recommended, but it will not prevent XSS in the general case. If it was possible, frameworks would already have this implemented. The only robust and actually secure solution against XSS is output encoding at the place of output, because before that you don't have the context to select the proper encoding.

Comment: How do you mean output encoding? So i will get data from database and before I send it to front-end I will check the string if it is not somehow encoded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent people from doing XSS in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147958/how-do-i-prevent-people-from-doing-xss-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: That filter doesn't prevent XSS. For example, an input of `<vbscript:script>alert(1)<vbscript:/script>` produces `<script>alert(1)</script>`. If the front-end has XSS flaws then that's what should be fixed. Follow the rules at https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html and https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score -1):

You should to implement a filter to sanitize the parameters. Take a view to following [link](http://scrumbucket.org/sanitize-your-spring-mvc-controller/)