# What alternatives are there to Hibernate Validator's @SafeHtml to validate Strings?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

As stated in the JavaDocs, it will be removed in a future release. 
Is there any alternative library which works similarly via annotations?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's first explain the reasons of the deprecation: we recently had a security issue (CVE) due to this very constraint. It was due to an error in our implementation but it made us realize that this was very fragile and potentially a can of worms security wise.

The alternative for now would be to implement it yourself based on our latest implementation and maintain it in your own application (with potentially your own tweaks).

We have a very nice article on our blog explaining how to do that easily: https://in.relation.to/2017/03/02/adding-custom-constraint-definitions-via-the-java-service-loader/ .

Basically, this change is us saying that we don't want to take the responsibility of something that is potentially fragile and will need a lot of attention, with tweaks potentially specific to the application platform it is deployed on.

Update: I have posted a full announcement here: https://in.relation.to/2019/11/20/hibernate-validator-610-6018-released/ .

Comment: Is there a reason why the documentation doesn't provide any information on why it's going to be removed?

Comment: Not really. TBH, I haven't had the time to properly announce these releases yet. There will be a blog post and migration notes soon. I'll work on that this week.

Comment: Could you provide a link or some details on the security issue?

Comment: Never mind, I found it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1739

Comment: @DarioSeidl the blog post is here: https://in.relation.to/2019/11/20/hibernate-validator-610-6018-released/ . I will update my message.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Thank you, we will explore to create our own validators in the future

Comment: It is error prone, so let's make it a user problem, then the world will definitely be a safer place. It's a sad loss I think, but I understand the decision.

Answer (score 6):

My solution:

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

NoHtml.java

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NoHtmlValidator.class)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface NoHtml {
    String message() default "Unsafe html content";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

NoHtmlValidator.java

```
public class NoHtmlValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NoHtml, String> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        return value == null || Jsoup.isValid(value, Safelist.none());
    }
}
```

Any bean:

```
@NoHtml
private String name;
```

See [jsoup - Sanitize HTML](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsoup/jsoup_sanitize_html.htm) and [Sanitizing User Input, Part II (Validation with Spring REST)](https://thoughtfulsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/sanitizing-user-input-part-ii-validation-with-spring-rest)

UPDATE: change `Jsoup.clean..equals..` to `Jsoup.isValid`

Comment: Keep in mind that this approach suffers from the same CVE that caused SafeHtml to be removed from Hibernate Validator in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative for SafeHtml.
You can use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/safelist-sanitizer) and write custom annotation to achieve this.

First add Jsoup dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In this approach I write this to validate in field level, You can validate even in class level.
Write the annotation as below.

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = HTMLValidator.class)
public @interface CustomSafeHtml {
   String message() default "Unsafe HTML tags included";
   Class<?>[] groups() default {};
   public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then write the validator class, your validation logic goes here.

```
public class HTMLValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomSafeHtml,String 
{
  @Override
  public void initialize(CustomSafeHtml constraintAnnotation) {
     ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return Jsoup.isValid(s, Whitelist.basic());
  }
}
```

Finally add the annotation to your required fields. In my case I validate string fields.

```
@Data
public class VersionRequest extends BaseRequest {
  @CustomSafeHtml
  String version;
  EntityStatus status;
}
```

Comment: WhiteList is now depricated in favor of SafeList

Comment: No difference from 3-day early solution above